# I tried to write HTML code and wanted to align each div width according to its contents width without help of css

Tags: html

Here is the HTML code :

```
 <div style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 520px; WIDTH: 302px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 350px; HEIGHT: 92px; ">

   <div style="Z-INDEX:2; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; LEFT: 6px; WIDTH: 151px; POSITION: relative; TOP: 7px; HEIGHT: 19px">
  "Group Byyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" </div>

<div style="Z-INDEX:3;border-color: black; border-width: 1px;WIDTH: 153px; POSITION: absolute;left: 167px;  TOP: 7px; HEIGHT: 19px; ">
  "SummarizeBy"  </div>

<div style="Z-INDEX:4;border-color: black;  border-width: 1px;   WIDTH: 151px; POSITION: relative; TOP: 17px; HEIGHT: 18px; left: 9px;">
  "abc"  </div>



<div style="Z-INDEX:5;border-color: black; border-width: 1px;   WIDTH: 151px;  POSITION: absolute;  TOP: 36px;  HEIGHT: 56px; left: 171px">
  "pqr"    </div>

</div>
```

How to Auto Align the div width with contents width in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not asking why do you have your css inline styles. You mean to have div width the same as content width inside it? Try:

```
width: auto
```

Comment: by setting width : auto text will still get out of div.